# How to read Ansys data files in ParaView?

Tags: paraview

Anybody knows how to export an Ansys structural data file to ParaView?

It is read that ParaView has an Ansys reader, but it does not work. Errors always come up when loading the *.inp file.

Is there any script to convert .inp files to .vtk?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add an **ansys** tag to your question?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmsM2JZNT7g) from Czech-based SVS FEM s.r.o., I wrote an input file for Ansys Mechanical APDL, that creates a VTK file, which can be opened in ParaView.

In the input file `vtk.inp`, the user has to specify the argument `arg1`, for which the nodal values are to be written to the vtk file via the command `*get,my_results(j),NODE,n_j,...`, p.e.

```
arg1='S,EQV' ! for equivalent stress or
arg1='TEMP'  ! for temperature
```

For further nodal results, refer to the specifications of the `*GET` command in the [Ansys Commands Reference](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/17.2/en-us/help/ans_cmd/Hlp_C_GET.html#get.post.node).

The `vtk.inp` file should be placed in the current working directory. It is called with the APDL command `/input,vtk,inp`. In Ansys Mechanical, this command can directly be inserted in the command line. In Ansys Workbench, the command can be pasted in the feature `Commands (APDL)` under `Solution`.
The output file `output.vtk` is written in the same location as the input file.

The code was tested with a structural analysis in Ansys Mechanical APDL 17.2 and Ansys Workbench 17.2. The vtk file was tested with ParaView 5.4.1.

**Explanation:**

The array `e_types_Ansys_to_VTK` maps the Ansys element types (p. e. `SOLID186`) to VTK cell types (see also [Ansys Element Types](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/17.2/en-us/help/ans_elem/Hlp_E_CH3_2.html)).

**Limitations:**

- The input file is yet limited to write only one scalar parameter result in the vtk file, but it can easily be extended for vector or tensor results as well as for multiple results in one vtk file, following the [VTK File Format Specification](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Essingla/Research/file-formats.pdf).
- Since Ansys stores nodal results only in the corner nodes, only linear VTK elements are used. There could still be some minor mistakes in the `e_types_Ansys_to_VTK` map, since I could only test some element types. Please feel free to report any corrections or extensions to the code in the comments.

Here is the [link to the source code](https://pastebin.com/gyJHKTeJ). Use at your own risk.

Comment: This pastebin link doesn't work. Would you be able to post the source code again? 
It's a little unclear to me but are you able to achieve this purely using APDL commands? What exactly is the vtk.inp file that you mention?

Comment: @feedMe The pastebin link works. Please try again: https://pastebin.com/gyJHKTeJ Yes, you are right. The `output.vtk` file is directly written from the Ansys macro `vtk.inp`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you would like to export a vtk file directly from Ansys Workbench, a Python result converter was introduced in a Youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmsM2JZNT7g). Unfortunately, the source code only appears in the video and is explained in Czech language.

Thus, I typewrote the code from screenshots and made some minor improvements.

You will need two files to install the macro as an Ansys ACT extension:
[main.py](https://pastebin.com/qcHQdMju) and [vtk.xml](https://pastebin.com/CCgfFBMU).

1. Place the file `vtk.xml` in the folder `C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v###\Addins\ACT\extensions`, where `###` is your Ansys version, p.e. `172`
2. Create a new folder `vtk` in `C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v###\Addins\ACT\extensions`.
3. Place the file `main.py` in the created folder.
4. Start Ansys Workbench.
5. Register the path `C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v###\Addins\ACT\extensions` as additional extension path under `Tools > Options > Extensions`.
6. Restart Ansys Workbench, go to `Extensions > ACT start page > Extension manager > VTK` and load the extension.
7. In a structural analysis, go to `Results`, right-click and insert `My results`. Three inputs have to made by the user:
8. Under `*get,my_results(j),NODE,N,...,` , give the desired nodal result according to the [Ansys Commands Reference](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/17.2/en-us/help/ans_cmd/Hlp_C_GET.html#get.post.node), p.e. `S,EQV` for equivalent stress.
9. Under `VTF file name`, give the full path to the vtk output file to be created, p.e. `C:\temp\output.vtk`
10. Under `Load step`, give the load step number (p.e. `1` for last load step unless not stated otherwise).

For larger models, I experienced that the automatically generated file `makeresult.mac` is not instantly transferred from the `project_pending` folder to the actual working directory, thus, causing the macro to throw an error. Maybe, anyone can make a suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

ParaView cannot read .inp structure files (I guess this is the Abaqus file format). You could try to export your files as Nastran (.nas) files, since ParaView has a Nastran reader.